# Почему вью элементы не реагируют на перемещение?

Tags: ios, xcode

Вот решил заняться иос и при работе в борде я могу перетянуть элемент из списка и расположить там где мне нужно на экране.

Но потом когда я уже поставленный на экране элемент я хочу переместить куда нибудь он не реагирует ни на нажатие и удержание при перетягивании ни на двойной клик и перетягивание ...

Хотя в видео туториале это делается очень просто, взял и переместил куда нужно...

И второе насчет присваивания методов кнопкам, я так понял, что нужно зажать правую кнопку на элементе и потащить его в код и уже икскод предложит добавить метод.

Но я меня это тоже не работет... Нижимаю, зажимаю, кликаю, ничего... Только текст можно редаетировать и все.

Может где то есть что то вроде блокировки какой то? Или в настройках что то ?

Answer (score 0):

Перетаскивается как обычные иконки, попробуйте переустановить Xcode.

По поводу перетаскивания кнопок в код: это делается с зажатой клавишей Ctrl и удержанием левой кнопки :)